Why is my linker command producing an executable which segfaults?
I'm trying to learn more about the compilation process, so I've been using tools like cpp, as, and ld instead of putting everything through gcc. Here's what I have so far:
I have a simple main.c file:
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  printf("Hello, World!\n");
  return 0;
}

I then run these instructions on Linux to compile it and run it:
cpp -o main.i main.c           # Preprocess it for includes
gcc -o main.s -S main.i        # Compile it to assembly
as -o main.o main.s            # Assemble it into machine code
ld -o main main.o -e main -lc  # Link it (specify entry point isn't `_start` and include glibc)
ld.so ./main                   # Run it using the dynamic linker & loader

There are two things weird about this:

This code segfaults when it runs:

$ ld.so ./main
Hello, World!
Segmentation fault (core dumped)


My machine says the file is not found when I try to run it without ld.so:

$ ./main
bash: ./main: No such file or directory

But I'm sure the file is there and executable:
$ ls -l main
-rwxrwxr-x 1 snowden snowden 6232 May  4 18:33 mai

However, if I only change the ld stage to use gcc instead by running gcc -o main main.o, then the file is found and it doesn't segfault. So, what is causing my ld command to produce this buggy executable? I have a feeling that it's a problem with the -e main part of this command, but I'm not sure what else the entry point would be.
EDIT
Thanks Some programmer dude, this works:
ld -o main -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 main.o /lib64/crt*.o /lib64/libc.so

I still can't explain why this produced a "file not found" error. Also, I wish there was a more generic version of this command that would work on different machines. I think the location of these libraries will vary widely.
EDIT #2
I think I found out why I'm getting the file-not-found error. Although, it does still seem like the wrong error message:
$ ld -o main -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 main.o /lib64/crt*.o /lib64/libc.so
$ file main
main: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, not stripped
$ ./main
Hello, World!
$ ld -o main main.o /lib64/crt*.o /lib64/libc.so
$ file main
main: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld64.so.1, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, not stripped
$ ./main
bash: ./main: No such file or directory
$ ls /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
$ ls /lib/ld64.so.1
ls: cannot access '/lib/ld64.so.1': No such file or directory

As you can see, the main difference is that, without specifying -dynamic-linker, the interpreter for this file is set to /lib/ld64.so.1, which doesn't exist. This is weird because, if you look at the docs in ld for this flag, it says:

"The default dynamic linker is normally correct; don't use this unless you know what you are doing."

And it appears to be wrong in this case.
So, I'm guessing that, for some reason, when my OS tries to execute an ELF executable, if the interpreter is not found, it just says file not found: <original file name>, instead of saying that the file's interpreter is actually what wasn't found.

You don't link with the startup code, which sets up things like the stack (used for function calls) and the space used for global variables. And more importantly, the stdout output stream where printf writes. There's usually a file named crt0.o that is linked by the gcc front-end program. Do a normal build with just plain gcc main.c -o main -v. Note the -v flag to get a verbose build which shows a lot of information about how it builds your program, including the actual commands and options it invokes.

Execute gcc -v main.c and it will tell you what you can execute to do what it does.

Thanks @Someprogrammerdude. It looks like it works with ld -o main -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 main.o /lib64/crt1.o /lib64/libc.so /lib64/crti.o /lib64/crtn.o. I understand why this might have segfaulted before, but why the "file not found" error?

main is not the entry point of your program. On Unix systems, it is typically start or _start, which is an entry point in the C startup code that sets up the C environment that C programs need. After the startup code is done, it calls main.
